# find image name on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do simple thing but not sure how , I have couple images in html I want to click on them and console log on JavaScript the image name.

I would like to put all the images under 1 div so it will be easy to apply some css on them later ,

something like this

```
<div id="images" onclick="clickImageTest()">
  <img name ="a" src="./notes/a.png">
  <img name ="b" src="./notes/b.png">
  <img name ="c" src="./notes/c.png">
  <img name ="d" src="./notes/d.png">
</div>
```

the JS function will be :

```
function clickImageTest(){
  console.log(selectScaleOption);
}
```

but how do i do the getElement thing? to get each image name

```
var selectScaleOption = document.getElementsBy*****("images").xxx;
```

Comment: Are the images already in the `#images` element, or is that where you want to put them? What's the current representative "*[mcve]*" of your problem? What, specifically, do you want to do to those Images, what is `selectScaleOption` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through your images, and click on each one of them and add it to the other div

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img')
const container = document.getElementById('container')

images.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(el.name)
  container.innerHTML += `<img src="${el.src}" alt="${el.alt}" name="${el.name}" />`
}))
```

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

#images {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img name="a" alt="a" src="./notes/a.png" />
  <img name="b" alt="b" src="./notes/b.png" />
  <img name="c" alt="c" src="./notes/c.png" />
  <img name="d" alt="d" src="./notes/d.png" />
</div>

<div id="container"></div>
```

---

And to keep with your current code  - event delegation - you can do like this:

```js
const images = document.getElementById('images')
const container = document.getElementById('container')

images.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const el = e.target
  console.log(el.name)
  container.innerHTML += `<img src="${el.src}" alt="${el.alt}" name="${el.name}" />`
})
```

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

#images {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img name="a" alt="a" src="./notes/a.png" />
  <img name="b" alt="b" src="./notes/b.png" />
  <img name="c" alt="c" src="./notes/c.png" />
  <img name="d" alt="d" src="./notes/d.png" />
</div>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) (having a listener on a common parent instead of adding it to each sibling).It is a very powerful feature especially when you have an unknown number of dynamically created nodes. Having a single listener is much more performant for memory allocation.

You use the event parameter that is sent to the click listener, and there is the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property that will give you a reference to the node that triggered the click.

Hope this helps!